# How to check if a subset is compact and a k-dimensional submanifold?

Tags: calculus, manifolds, compactness, submanifold

I'm given the following subset S of $\mathbb{R}^4$: $$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + t^4 = 1$$
$$x + y + z + t = 1$$

Now, given these two, how do I show this is a compact set? I've looked at a number of examples but I'm very far behind on the knowledge required for this so I'm really not sure what to do. If anyone could provide an outline of what I need to do/use to show this, it would be super helpful!

I also needed to show that this set was a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$. I did this by calculating the gradient of both equations and equating them with a constant, and I got 2 sets of points, but they don't satisfy both the equations. I'm not exactly sure what to do next to show that it's a submanifold so any help in that regard would be really useful as well! :(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

For the Euclidean space $E=\mathbb{R}^4,$ a subset $A$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. The first equation (of unit sphere in $E$) gives that your intersection is bounded. The second equation is of a plane in $E$ and so is closed. A closed subset of a bounded set is closed and bounded. Therefore...

Comment: OH okay yeah, that's pretty straightforward. But how would I show that the first equation is bounded? Is there any particular proof I could look at for this? And why is the plane closed? (Also in this case, is the second equation a subset of the first equation?)

Comment: @Applesauce44 The first equation says that in $E$ the distance squared from $(0,0,0,0)$ to the point $(x,y,z,t)$ is $1.$ Thus the first equation describes the unit ball in $E$ around the origin, which is clearly bounded.

Comment: As for the plane being closed: define $h(x,y,z,t)=x+y+z+t-1.$ Then $h$ is a continuous function on $E$ which is $0$ for points *on* the plane and nonzero for points *off* the plane. So the complement of the plane is the open set defined by $h(x,y,z,t) \neq 0$ and so its complement, i.e. the plane, is closed.

Comment: @Applesauce44 Just added why the plane is closed, and in previous comment put why the intersection you are looking at is compact. Let me know if more questions.

Comment: YES thank you very much, this is very helpful!! 
Just one last thing, you said the first equation is the distance squared, but it's to the fourth power? Does the reasoning for it being closed still stay the same?

Comment: It would be the distance squared from the origin to the point $(x^2,y^2,z^2,t^2).$ [Sorry I didn't adjust my comment correctly. ] Either way, since that is set to $1$ it's the same as saying the distance squared from the origin to the point $(x,y,z,t)$ is $1.$

Comment: Ohh yes alright, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121325/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-applesauce44).